# How to convert free disk space to GB and print it

Tags: java, arraylist, ssh, cmd

Using `ssh.addCmd("wmic logicaldisk get caption, FreeSpace");`
 I am able to get the Free disk space of Windows machine in bits

```
================Response =============================

Caption  FreeSpace    
C:       13845487616  
D:       91357184000  
E:       0 

================Response =============================
```

Above response is been saved to and string "response" and able to print it.

I need code help to covert the bits to MB or GB and display in the below format.

```
=================================================

Caption  FreeSpace    
C:       1.73 GB  
D:       11.41 GB  
E:       0 GB

=====================================================

// Displays results of Tomcat nodes
import sshtool.Ssh;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
JTextArea textarea = out;

def serverUserList =
    [

        "Servername or IP",
    ];

final myLock = new Object[0];
int i = 0,j=0,k=0;
//String myArr [] = new String[50];
for(server in serverUserList){
    Ssh ssh = new Ssh(){
        @Override
        public void finished(String cmd, String response){
            synchronized(myLock){

                textarea.append(this.ip +"\n");
                textarea.append( response);
            }
        }
    };
    //Stagger SSH connections by delaying each thread.
    ssh.setThreadDelayTime(3000*i);
    ssh.setIp(server);
    ssh.setGatewayIp("GatewayIP or Name");
    //ssh.setSharingSingletonGateway(true);
    ssh.setUsername("Domain\\Username");
    ssh.setKey("Password");
    ssh.addCmd("wmic logicaldisk get caption, FreeSpace");

    ssh.start();
}
```

Comment: This is mostly a numerical conversion problem. [Here's the conversion](http://www.matisse.net/bitcalc/). Bits / 8 = Bytes. Bytes / 1024 = Kilobytes. Kilobytes / 1024 = Megabytes. Megabytes / 1024 = Gigabytes. You can use an int for all but the last calculation to gigabytes, where you want to use a double for decimal accuracy.

Comment: That being said, some of this looks like Java, but some of this doesn't. I would recommend giving us the snippet where you have an int or String with the value and require conversion and output.

Comment: It is unclear why you can not write this code yourself. This is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a simple test to convert bytes to kilobytes, megabytes, or gigabytes.

Here are the test results:

```
13845487616 -> 12.89 GB
91357184000 -> 85.08 GB
123 -> 0.12 KB
1234 -> 1.21 KB
123456789 -> 117.74 MB
```

And here's the code:

```
package com.ggl.testing;

public class PrintBytes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long bytes = 13845487616L;
        System.out.println(bytes + " -> " + convertBytes(bytes));
        bytes = 91357184000L;
        System.out.println(bytes + " -> " + convertBytes(bytes));
        bytes = 123L;
        System.out.println(bytes + " -> " + convertBytes(bytes));
        bytes = 1234L;
        System.out.println(bytes + " -> " + convertBytes(bytes));
        bytes = 123456789L;
        System.out.println(bytes + " -> " + convertBytes(bytes));
    }

    public static String convertBytes(long bytes) {
        long kbDivisor = 1024L;
        long mbDivisor = kbDivisor * kbDivisor;
        long gbDivisor = mbDivisor * kbDivisor;

        if (bytes <= mbDivisor) {
            double kb = (double) bytes / kbDivisor;
            return String.format("%.2f", kb) + " KB";
        } else if (bytes <= gbDivisor) {
            double mb = (double) bytes / mbDivisor;
            return String.format("%.2f", mb) + " MB";
        } else {
            double gb = (double) bytes / gbDivisor;
            return String.format("%.2f", gb) + " GB";
        }

    }

}
```